# Позиционировать абсолютно элемент относительно другого элемента без CSS

Tags: javascript, css

Итак, есть один элемент с плавающей шириной. И второй элемент, который нужно абсолютным позиционированием прикрепить к первому точно снизу, и точно по ширине.

```
<style>
    #first {
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 80%;
        padding: 20px;
        background: red;
    }
    #second {
        background: blue;
        padding: 20px;
    }
</style>
<div id="first">blabla</div>
<div id="second">blabla</div>
```

По ряду причин, сделать это с помощью CSS в данном конкретном случае не получится, придется использовать JS, в котором я не силён, и буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: ты хочешь через js ему стилей дать?

Comment: @AndreyFreiz именно, взять расстояние слева и справа от #first и дать их в качестве left и right для #second

Comment: Что вам мешает изучить js?

Comment: @Митяй собственная тупость, или нехватка времени, или то, что я по основной специальности сеошник, и js мне бывает нужен почти никогда. Выбирайте сами. Я бы с удовольствием заплатил за решение моей задачи, если бы здесь и сейчас кто-то мог помочь. Но никого нет, а надо быстро - поэтому, задаю вопросы.

Comment: @Александр И всё таки он вам нужен)

Comment: Слишком туманная цель, лично я не вижу смысла здесь использовать js. То, что вы описали в задаче можно получить обернув 2 элемента родительским контейнером, задать элементам габариты 100% родительского контейнера, а регулировать уже родительский компонент.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const first = document.getElementById('first');
const second = document.getElementById('second');

window.onresize = positionSecond;

positionSecond();

function positionSecond(){
    const rect = first.getBoundingClientRect();
    const width = getComputedStyle(first).getPropertyValue('width');

    second.style.position = 'absolute';
    second.style.top = rect.bottom + 'px';
    second.style.left = rect.left + 'px';
    second.style.width = width;
}
```

```html
<style>
    #first {
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 80%;
        padding: 20px;
        background: red;
    }
    #second {
        background: blue;
        padding: 20px;
    }
</style>
<div id="first">blabla</div>
<div id="second">blabla</div>
```